# Volume of tetrahedron(12)

Tags: geometry

Given a regular tetrahedron T of the edge length a. Extend all edges of T beyond all vertices by a. In this way, twelve new points are created.

What is the volume of the body spanned by these twelve points as in Figure A 591214 a, as a function of the volume V of the tetrahedron T?

[image]

Comment: $63V$, see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344522)  (which is essentially the same question)

Comment: So at the end i shoud get 21√2 / 4 x p^3
If i understood it good?

Comment: Yes, you will get $\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4} a^3$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I understood it now